# SharePoint 2013 solution deployment stuck with Not having access to DB

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, deployment, farm-solution

While installing the solution on production it was stuck there for longer time. When ran the `stsadm -o enumdeployments command`, it is giving me following error

```
<State>Pending</State>Cannot open database "SharePoint_AdminContent_787abc
fa-6bb1-4e7b-b6d7-ac240266cc12" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'xxx\xxxxx'.
```

That means permissions got changed or any other reason?

Answer (score 0):

Error indicating that permission on central admin db is missing.

- Make Sure Farm Account ( Running SharePoint timer service ) should have db owner rights
- You Also Login With Farm Admin Account and run the script.
- Open Power Shell " Run As Administrator"